# Is there a NY tax form to use when one is missing a K-1 (or 1065) from an LLC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company

I invested in an LLC that has for the most part gone under.  The LLC exists but I do not think that I will receive a K-1 for for 2011.  My understanding is that there is a tax form I can fill out to tell the government that a K-1 will not be available.

Is anyone familiar with this form?  I can't seem to find it anywhere?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form 10-K is filed by corporations to SEC. You must be thinking of form 1065 (its schedule K) that a partnership (and **multi-member** LLC) must file with the IRS.

Unless the multi-member LLC is legally dissolved, it **must** file this form. You're a member, so it is your responsibility, with all the other members, to make sure that the manager files all the forms, and if the manager doesn't - fire the manager and appoint another one (or, if its member managed - chose a different member to manage).

If you're a sole member of the LLC - then you don't need to file any forms with the IRS, all the business expenses and credits are done on your Schedule C, as if you were a sole propriator.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to contact the manager.  I'm not the only one either.  There are four partners, one being me, who are looking to resign but are unable to due to silence.  I need to file my personal taxes and my understanding is that I can include a orm that states that I didn't receive a 10-k.  I was hoping to fill this form out but I can't find it or any information regarding it.

Comment: @skimobear - do you have operational agreement? You should have one. Act based on it. If majority of the members votes to dissolve - it will be dissolved. If majority of the members votes to appoint a different manager - so it will be. Are you in contact with all (or most of all) the other partners? Make a decision, document the decision, and act upon the decision. If you're part of a pool of investors, and cannot get a hold of all the rest of the partners - you should turn to the agent of service in the state the LLC is registered at. Talk to an attorney, if you cannot resolve it on your own.

Comment: I do have an agreement.  The 'executive manager' is the only one left on the executive team and he is not reachable.  The agreement states that I need to submit my resignation to someone on the executive team but he is the only one left and he wont co-operate.

Comment: then you need an attorney.

Comment: @skimobear: Most agreements I've seen allow one or members to force a meeting. Like littleadv says, you can propose to fire the 'executive manager' at the meeting and replace him with someone cooperative; or you can vote to dissolve the LLC.